# OSError sometimes occurs when opening .txt files in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that takes in the words of a .txt file then creates a new .txt file containing only the words with more than 5 letters. To do this I have the `with open` command twice. Here is the code I have so far.

```
iteration=0
while iteration < 101:
    with open(r"‪C:\Users\user\Documents\filename.txt", "r") as file1:
       inputwords=file1.readlines()[1]
    wordtest=list(inputwords)
    wordstr=''.join(wordtest)
words=len(wordtest)
    if words>=5:
        print(wordstr + " is longer then 5 letters")
        with open(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newfile.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("\n" +wordstr)
    iteration+=1
```

When I run it gives me an **OSError** but when I remove the first `with open` it doesn't give me an OSError and works fine. I'm using Windows 10 and the error message is:
**OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\Users\user\Documents\filename.txt'**
Also I have attempted using double back-slashes and I get the same error. This has happened in other scripts and in one case every few times I attempted opening the script it worked fine, other times it returned the  **OSError**

Comment: Is the second `with open`  nested inside the first or after it? Opens it the same file? Which OS? Is there a more detailed error message (error number)?

Comment: We need the full code (with dummy variables is fine) and the full error traceback to help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: You have an invisible Unicode control character in your pathname string, which was likely pasted from somewhere else.  There's an explanation of how this might happen at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924  To fix, select the `"C` at the start of the string, delete it, then retype those two characters.

Comment: @jasonharper is correct ... the traceback is very clear about the fact that there is a Unicode character in the file name (`\u202a`) prior to the `C`

Comment: @jasonharper Oh, I didn't realize that would happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue with the file path you're passing in.

as per your code you're passing the path as

```
with open(r"‪C:\Users\\Documents\filename.txt", "r") as file1:
```

if you're passing the raw string as path then simply give the path in the statement as below instead of having double backslash.

```
with open(r"‪C:\Users\Documents\filename.txt", "r") as file1:
```

or you can simply use single slash

```
c:/users/path
```

or double backslash (given twice to avoid the special meaning of backslash as an escape sequence)

```
c:\\users\\path
```

Comment: The double backslash is from where I removed the user area. It had my name in it and I didn't want that there. Sorry if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: when you are passing your path in r' ' it will take it as a raw string and hence no escape characters are needed. And after you edit to the question could see a invisible unicode character being pasted. To avoid that instead of copying the path from the dialogue box just type the same manually. That will avoid that Unicode character issue. Here you can simple delete the line and type the entire line manually.